# Executing API in cypress returning ip address instead of body

Tags: cypress

```
     it.only('Task 1 - 2: Send Post request', ()=>{
    
      cy.request({
        method : 'POST',
        url: 'http://ptsv2.com/t/fu807-1554722621/post',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Basic YXV0b21hdGU6ZXZlcnl0aGluZw=='
        }
      })        
    }).then((res)=>{

      cy.log(res.body)
     
    })
  })
```

its giving `log{ "ip": "192.168.2.2", "token": "0799249366" }`

expected outcome:

{
"username": "automate",
"password": "everything",
"targetUrl": "http://ptsv2.com/t/7ty82-1554722743/post"
}

Comment: when I open the url `http://ptsv2.com/t/fu807-1554722621/post` in the browser , which is equivalent of making a GET request without any headers I get the expected response body.

Comment: yes... but it has to be a post request.
POSTMAN gives the expected outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it gives me an error because in your code `.then()` is chained to the `it()` block. I adjusted the test and got the expected output

```js
  it.only("Task 1 - 2: Send Post request", () => {
    cy.request({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://ptsv2.com/t/fu807-1554722621/post",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Basic YXV0b21hdGU6ZXZlcnl0aGluZw==",
      },
    }).then((res) => {
      cy.log(res.body);
    });
  });
```

[image: test result]

Comment: Strangely the same response comes back from `POST` or `GET`. But I think this isn't a real-world API.

Comment: it worked... yes its dummy